# How to make Net::OpenSSH exit if authentication fails?

Tags: perl

I'm connecting to a remote server using Net::OpenSSH.

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new(
              $server, 
              user => $user_name, 
              passwd => $password, 
              strict_mode => 0, 
              master_opts => ['-v']
);
```

This hangs when the authentication fails/when a wrong password is specified.

```
OpenSSH_6.0p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8d 28 Sep 2006
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/software/etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 10.53.34.200 [10.53.34.200] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

It's hanging in the above line.

Setting "$Net::OpenSSH::debug=-1;" returns:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
# file object not yet found at /usr/hema/.libnet-openssh-perl/diag-10.53.34.200-21463-907722
# file object not yet found at /usr/hema/.libnet-openssh-perl/diag-10.53.34.200-21463-907722
```

How to make it exit in such case?

Comment: enable debugging `$Net::OpenSSH::debug=-1;` and append the output to your question.

Comment: Could you include **all** the output?

Answer (score 1):

As from the module documentation here is the way of handling errors:

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host);
$ssh->error and
die "Couldn't establish SSH connection: ". $ssh->error;
```

Comment: It's establishing the connection with the host. Only the authentication failure causes hung